# Ex: Object reference not set to an instance of an object when write strings to log file

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code

```
 private Log in_log;
 in_log = new Log(logfolder + call_date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "\\" + call_number + ".log");
```

Then

```
    private void AppLog(string s1,string s2)
    {
        if (Environment.UserInteractive) Log.Write(s1, s2);
        try
        {
            in_log.Write(s1, s2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.WriteException(ex,":Logging:AppLog" );
        }
    }
```

I got an exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

at in_log.Write(s1, s2);

The Write methods in Log are:

```
    public void Write(string LogEntry);
    public void Write(int logLevel, string LogEntry);
    public void Write(string s, params object[] args);
    public void Write(int logLevel, string s, params object[] args);
```

I think something wrong of using

> params object[] args

The call process:

```
call_number = "H_20131106081139199_69";
AppLog("Answering Call Number:{0}", call_number);
```

Thanks for correction.

Comment: Everytime you write `+ "\\" +` remember [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) :)

Comment: Post the definition of the Writemethod that you are calling.  It is likely that your nullref is happening inside of it, unless in_log is already null.

Comment: Are you sure `in_log` is initialized when that is called?  All we have between those code blocks is the comment "Then" which doesn't prove anything.  How are these code blocks related?  When you debug this, what object is `null`?  Is it `in_log` or something else?  Where was that object supposed to be set?

Comment: @A.R.: Building a path with `Path.Combine` is much more readable and less error-prone. You don't need to think about directory separator chars(`\\\` or `\\` or `/` on unix,...) or if the first part of the path does or does not end in "\" and whether the second part of the path does not does not start with "\". You can concentrate on the important part, the directories and filenames.

Comment: The problem appears to be with in_log initialization.  However, you have not told us if the init is in a field, cstor, or method.  So this question lacks the info to answer.

Comment: @Love: Please Debug and see what is the exact value of logfolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason you'd get that error on that line is because `in_log` is null. Check you are actually calling the line `in_log = new Log(...` before you reach this line of code.

Having said that, are you sure that the exception is being thrown by that line, or within the Write method itself? If the latter, you'll have to post the code for the method for further help.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure the in_log in scope when you use it to write string into.